# loadHTMLString is not loading images from a website

Tags: ios, swift2, wkwebview

I'm loading part of the HTML content of a website onto a `WKWebView`. The part I'm trying to load sometimes contains an image. Using

```
webView.loadHTMLString(url, baseURL: nil)
```

gives me the following image:

[image: The image is a screen shot of the WKWebView running a piece of the HTML (the HTML is coming from a website) on the simulator]

Instead of the image being displayed a question mark is there.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the image’s URL?

Comment: Assuming that the `IMG` tags inside the HTML are relative URLs, then, as Matt said, you have to specify a baseURL.

Comment: Yes the tags are inside & when I put the websites URL as the base URL it still shows the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `baseURL: nil`. You need to supply the actual base URL! Otherwise, how can the image URL be resolved?

Comment: it still shows the same thing. setting the base url seems like common sense but it doesn't want to work. any suggestions?

Comment: Well, as Pekka said, look at the image's URL and see for yourself what the problem is.

Comment: Also, you know you can't do an `http://` URL without special settings in your _Info.plist_, right?

Comment: yes I do know that. The Arbitrary Loads are set to YES. Im not sure exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid if you're not willing to share the actual URL, I can't help any further. We're speaking entirely in generalities. :(